# Postgres and c3p0 invalid timezone error during connection

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, c3p0

I get the following error when trying to connect a standalone Java application to Postgres:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: invalid value for parameter "TimeZone": "America/New_York"
   at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.readStartupMessages(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java 572)
   ...
   at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriveManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriveManagerDataSource.java: 164)
   ...

(sorry, I have to type this in by hand because of my setup).

I am using Postgres 9.3.3 with PostGIS 2.1.1 extensions, the Postgres 9.3-1100 jdbc driver and the 0.2.6.3 c3p0 library.

I get this on both Linux and Windows systems. When I changed the TZ to GMT on the Linux system the connection works, but that's not a good solution.

Any idea what I con do to fix this?

Thanks,

Ken

Comment: Seems like there is something wrong with the PostgreSQL installation. Can you check `SELECT * FROM pg_timezone_names WHERE name = 'America/New_York'`?

Comment: That showed the problem. There were permission problems on the /usr/local/pgsql_933/share/timezone directories. I fixed those and I can connect now.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Don't forget to write it as an answer so others with the same problem know what to check.

Answer (score 2):

Pavel Horal had the correct answer. The Postgres installation was messed up and only root had access to the /usr/local/pgsql_933/share/timezone/America directory. Once I did a chmod on that and the files in it my problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

Check your default timezone in postgresql(UTC) and make sure connection timezone and default are same.